# Different methods to unpack CUDA half2 datatypes

Tags: cuda, simd, half-precision-float

I have some CUDA code which uses the `half2` datatype. It should be just two 16 bit floating point numbers packed together in a 32 bit space.

Apparently there are the methods `__low2half` and `__high2half` which convert a `half2` vector into a single `half` number. But there is also `.x` and `.y` on this vector. Most of the time these are the same, so this code works runs through most of the time:

```cpp
assert(q.x == __low2half(q));
assert(q.y == __high2half(q));
```

However, there are some kernel runs where this doesn't hold. These are cases where they are not the same:

```
x=-57344,       y=-53376,   low=0.234497,   high=-0.17041
x=-inf,         y=nan,      low=0.00634766, high=0.473877
x=nan,          y=nan,      low=-0.0716553, high=0.540039
x=0,            y=0,        low=0,          high=0
x=3.8147e-05,   y=nan,      low=nan,        high=nan
x=-61440,       y=nan,      low=-0.999512,  high=0.31958
```

Which way of accessing them is correct, then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There should be no behavioral difference if properly applied.

Per [IEEE definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565164/what-is-the-rationale-for-all-comparisons-returning-false-for-ieee754-nan-values), `nan` values are never equal to anything.

Apart from that, a simple exhaustive test case passes:

```
# cat t106.cu
#include <cuda_fp16.h>
#include <cstdio>
__global__ void k(){

  for (size_t qs = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x; qs < 0x100000000ULL; qs += gridDim.x*blockDim.x){
    unsigned qu = (unsigned)qs;
    half2 q = *(reinterpret_cast<half2 *>(&qu));
    if (!__isnan(q.x)) if (q.x != __low2half(q))  printf("fail x: %u\n", qu);
    if (!__isnan(q.y)) if (q.y != __high2half(q)) printf("fail y: %u\n", qu);
  }
}

int main(){

  k<<<1024,256>>>();
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  }

# nvcc -o t106 t106.cu
# ./t106
#
```

If you want to see e.g. `nan` values printed out, omit the first if-test in each case.

I wouldn't be able to respond to a claim about a specific test case unless a complete example of that test case is given.  However I claim that your test case is not valid if it produces a result suggesting inequality, subject to above treatment.

Comment: Thank you for this exhaustive test. This means that both forms are equivalent and that there is something super weird going on elsewhere in my code. It already really helps to be able to rule that out. — The hint that “nan ≠ nan” is also helpful, this gives false positives in my assertion. But that's likely not the root cause.